# Userform - Type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, types, userform, mismatch

I am new to coding (2 months) and I mostly rip code from the net. For context, I am following some instructions from [here](http://yodalearning.com/tutorials/update-delete-using-excel-vba-userform-vba-userform/)  for how to update the values in my worksheet with a `userform`.

The first bit is fine, I am able to pull the data from my worksheet back into the `userform` where I am able to edit, but trying to then update the data in the worksheet is giving me a 'type mismatch' error.  Code below for when I click the 'update' button

```
Private Sub cmdupdate_Click()

If Me.cmbslno.Value = "" Then

MsgBox "SL No Can Not be Blank!!!", vbExclamation, "SL No"

Exit Sub

End If

Sheets("Sheet 1").Select

Dim rowselect As String

rowselect = Me.cmbslno.Value


Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.TextBoxdate.Value

Cells(rowselect, 3) = Me.TextBoxraisedby.Value

Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.ComboBoxsite.Value

Cells(rowselect, 6) = Me.ComboBoxfacility.Value

Cells(rowselect, 7) = Me.ComboBoxpdriver.Value

Cells(rowselect, 8) = Me.TextBoxissue.Value

Cells(rowselect, 9) = Me.TextBoxconsequence.Value

Cells(rowselect, 10) = Me.TextBoxmitigation.Value

Cells(rowselect, 11) = Me.TextBoximpact.Value

Cells(rowselect, 12) = Me.TextBoxlikely.Value

Cells(rowselect, 13) = Me.TextBoximpact.Value



End Sub
```

I am getting a type mismatch on the  `Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.TextBoxdate.Value stage`.  `Me.cmbslno.Value` is a short numeric `unique ID`.

I have copied that guide above exactly - aside from renaming things accordingly - so got no idea what the problem is.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are the current values of `Me.cmbslno.Value` and `Me.TextBoxdate.Value` when it crashes?  (I don't like the fact that you are using a `String` for the row number, but it **should** work - unless `Me.cmbslno.Value` is something that can't be converted to an integral number.)

Comment: @YowE3K - yup, `string` should work, VBA is clever enough to parse it as a `long`.

Comment: @Vityata But it could be a problem if the "short numeric unique ID" was something like `153.124` - No, forget I said that, it would round it to 153

Comment: @YowE3K - in my case `153.124` is "rounded" to `153124` ... :)

Comment: @Vityata LOL - that's what you get for having non-Australian numeric formats!!  (Even the Americans are smart enough to use our format.)

Answer (score 1):

2 possible problems:

1. rowselect is less than 1
2. Some issues with the selection.

Try it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdupdate_Click()

    If Me.cmbslno.Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "SL No Can Not be Blank!!!", vbExclamation, "SL No"

        Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim rowselect As Long
    rowselect = Me.cmbslno.Value

    If rowselect < 1 Then MsgBox "WRONG VALUE"

    With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
        .Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.TextBoxdate.Value
        .Cells(rowselect, 3) = Me.TextBoxraisedby.Value
        .Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.ComboBoxsite.Value
        .Cells(rowselect, 6) = Me.ComboBoxfacility.Value
        .Cells(rowselect, 7) = Me.ComboBoxpdriver.Value
        .Cells(rowselect, 8) = Me.TextBoxissue.Value
        .Cells(rowselect, 9) = Me.TextBoxconsequence.Value
        .Cells(rowselect, 10) = Me.TextBoxmitigation.Value
        .Cells(rowselect, 11) = Me.TextBoximpact.Value
        .Cells(rowselect, 12) = Me.TextBoxlikely.Value
        .Cells(rowselect, 13) = Me.TextBoximpact.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

This is how I fix them in the code above:

1. I make a check for the `rowselect` < 1. It would give an error, if the `rowselect` has a string value.
2. I use `With Worksheets("Sheet 1")`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help so far.  I have also used Thunderframes advice below and that has fixed my type mismatch error.  The issue I am having now is the selection I make (cmbslno) will always  select the top row of data (2nd row if you dismiss the top row being the header).  For info the unique id for 'cmbslno' is a 1.1 decimal.  Therefore for example if I select

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help so far.  I have also used Thunderframes advice below and that has fixed my type mismatch error.  The issue I am having now is the selection I make (cmbslno) will always select the top row of data (2nd row if you dismiss the top row being the header).  For info the unique id for 'cmbslno' is a 1.1 decimal - starting at 1.1.  Therefore for example no matter if I  select 2.2, 2.5 or 3.1 it will return and update the 1.1 row

Answer (score 1):

The `Cells` property accepts 2 arguments, both of which should be numeric:

You need to ensure that the value of `Me.cmbslno.Value` is numeric (or converted to a number), and that the variable you ar currently using, `rowselect`, is declared as a `Long`.

```
Dim rowselect As Long
If IsNumeric(Me.cmbslno.Value) Then
    rowselect = Me.cmbslno.Value
    Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.TextBoxdate.Value
    '...
End If
```

Comment: "both of which should be numeric" - the row needs to be convertible to numeric, but the column can be expressed as a string (e.g. `Cells("123","X")` is valid, because `"123"` [much as I dislike seeing it] can be converted to `123` to give a numeric row, and `"X"` is a perfectly valid column as it is)

Comment: @YowE3K Indeed, I hate seeing that too (and I've seen code that does it's own letter-index to integer conversion, yuck), so I guess I should have said accepts 2 *indexes*, which must resolve to row and column positions or labels.